# Dialogflow chatbot integration with Dialogflow

Tags: javascript, python, django, dialogflow-es

I have been following google codelab's exercise to integrate dialogflow chatbot with django web app and deploy it on google cloud platform. But I am unable to do so. Please help me out as I am fairly new to all of these and I have been trying a lot to solve the issues but nothing happened.

[Link to the Codelab: Create Front-end Django Client for Dialogflow Application](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/chatbots-dialogflow-django-frontend/#12)

My app's views.py file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
import dialogflow
import os
import json
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
#from dialogflow_v2 import dialogflow_v2 as Dialogflow
# Create your views here.

@require_http_methods(['GET'])
def index_view(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def convert(data):
    if isinstance(data, bytes):
        return data.decode('ascii')
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return dict(map(convert, data.items()))
    if isinstance(data, tuple):
        return map(convert, data)

    return data

@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def chat_view(request):
    print("FIRST STOP")
    print('Body', request.body)
    input_dict = convert(request.body)

    input_text = json.loads(input_dict)['text']

    GOOGLE_AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME = "project_on_gcp.json"
    current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    path = os.path.join(current_directory, GOOGLE_AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME)
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = path

    GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID = "project_id"
    session_id = "1234567891"
    context_short_name = "does_not_matter"

    context_name = "projects/" + GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID + "/agent/sessions/" + session_id + "/contexts/" + \
               context_short_name.lower()

    parameters = dialogflow.types.struct_pb2.Struct()
    #parameters["foo"] = "bar"

    context_1 = dialogflow.types.context_pb2.Context(
        name=context_name,
        lifespan_count=2,
        parameters=parameters
    )
    query_params_1 = {"contexts": [context_1]}

    language_code = 'en'

    response = detect_intent_with_parameters(
        project_id=GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
        session_id=session_id,
        query_params=query_params_1,
        language_code=language_code,
        user_input=input_text
    )
    return HttpResponse(response.query_result.fulfillment_text, status=200)

def detect_intent_with_parameters(project_id, session_id, query_params, language_code, user_input):
    """Returns the result of detect intent with texts as inputs.

    Using the same `session_id` between requests allows continuation
    of the conversaion."""
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
    print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session))

    #text = "this is as test"
    text = user_input

    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
        text=text, language_code=language_code)

    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

    response = session_client.detect_intent(
        session=session, query_input=query_input,
        query_params=query_params
    )

    print('=' * 20)
    print('Query text: {}'.format(response.query_result.query_text))
    print('Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})\n'.format(
        response.query_result.intent.display_name,
        response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence))
    print('Fulfillment text: {}\n'.format(
        response.query_result.fulfillment_text))

    return response


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'chat/about.html')
```

My urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('chat/', views.chat_view, name='chat-home'),
    path('', views.index_view, name='index'),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My Home.html page where I have the chatbot:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Django Dialogflow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}"/>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="page-header text-center">
        <h1>Dialogflow</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
          <ul class="list-group js-chat-log">
          </ul>

          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-btn">   
              <button class="btn btn-primary js-say">Submit</button>
            </span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/js.cookie.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
      var $chatlog = $('.js-chat-log');
      var $input = $('.js-text');
      var formData = new FormData(this);

      var $sayButton = $('.js-say');
      var dialogflowUrl = '{% url "index" %}';
      var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

      function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
      }

      $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
          }
        }
      });

      function createRow(text) {
        var $row = $('<li class="list-group-item"></li>');
        var list = '<li class="list-group-item">'
         var k = text.split("\n")

         for(i=0;i<k.length;i++) {
             list += k[i]+"<br />"
         }

        list = list + "</li>"
        $row.text(list);
        $chatlog.append(list);
        //$chatlog.append(text);
      }

      window.onload = createRow('<b><font size="4" face="Lucida Console">Chat with Dialogflow</font></b>');

      function submitInput() {
        var inputData = {
          'text': $input.val()

        }
        // Display the user's input on the web page
        createRow(inputData.text);
        var dialogflowChatUrl = '{% url "chat-home" %}';
        var $submit = $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: dialogflowChatUrl,
          data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
          contentType: 'application/json',
        });



        $submit.done(function(statement) {
            //createRow(statement.text);
            createRow(statement);
            console.log("this is", statement)
            // Clear the input field
            $input.val('');
        });

        $submit.fail(function() {
          // TODO: Handle errors
        });
      }

      $sayButton.click(function() {
        submitInput();
      });

      $input.keydown(function(event) {
        // Submit the input when the enter button is pressed
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          submitInput();
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Settings.py file :

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
SECRET_KEY = '6l^@!6)2*0d+xach78%=_y39$5abzuycs&9ke3s)y_u8@lpb4n'
DEBUG = True

# SECURITY WARNING: App Engine's security features ensure that it is safe to
# have ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] when the app is deployed. If you deploy a Django
# app not on App Engine, make sure to set an appropriate host here.
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'chat.apps.ChatConfig',
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'chat',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

# Dialogflow settings
DIALOGFLOW = {
    'client_access_token': 'client_access_token',
}

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

# Install PyMySQL as mysqlclient/MySQLdb to use Django's mysqlclient adapter
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers
# for more information
import pymysql  # noqa: 402
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

# [START db_setup]
if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/connection_name',
            'USER': 'username',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
            'NAME': 'database_name',
        }
    }
else:
    # Running locally so connect to either a local MySQL instance or connect to
    # Cloud SQL via the proxy. To start the proxy via command line:
    #
    #     $ cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:3306
    #
    # See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-proxy
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '3306',
            'USER': 'username',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
            'NAME': 'database_name',
        }
    }
# [END db_setup]


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',  # noqa: 501
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',  # noqa: 501
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',  # noqa: 501
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',  # noqa: 501
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL ='/media/'

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'google.com',
    'hostname.example.com',
    'localhost:8000',
    '127.0.0.1:9000'
)
```

I would be extremely grateful for all the help I get.

Comment: You say you are "unable to do so". Can you update your question to show what errors you're getting, or what you are doing that triggers the problems you're seeing? The more information you provide the better your chances are of getting a useful response.